# SpriteKit: How to stop/reset rotation on physicsBody

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a sprite that bouncing around the screen using physics. I am trying to turn on and off the ability of said sprite to rotate.

In init of the scene I set the following:

```
ball.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
```

Works just fine. Later, in another method I allow it with:

```
ball.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
```

Things are working great. However, when I set it back to NO it just keeps on spinning. I checked the debugger and allowsRotation is indeed set to NO.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From apples documentation:

> The allowsRotation property determines whether forces can impart angular velocity on the body.

This means that when it is set to no, the ball will keep its spin, but not be affected further by forces.

Set .angularVelocity to 0, when you set the allowsRotation to 0.